# Character rotation (ActionScript 2.0)

Tags: actionscript-2, smartfoxserver

I have some characters in my game on SmartFoxServer BASIC. Characters are controlled using the mouse (like in SFS basic avatarchat example)
I need characters can be rotated in different directions (like in different children MMO, for example Club Penguin).

My character is drawn with 8 sides (East, South-East, South, South-West, West, North-West, North, North-East).
How can I do it ? ActionScript 2.0

Maybe someone here have already made a similar on SFS? Or simply advise how this can be implemented ..
I know that it does not need to do anything on server-side.

(sorry for my english, I am not from an English-speaking country)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I have not tested the following answer myself as I don't have testing environment currently:

1. Create a movieclip in your stage and insert the character sprites in individual frames of the layer sequentially.
2. Test to see if your character is rotating clockwise as expected starting from East.
3. Name the movieclip as "hero" for an instance.
4. Try the following code:

**Actionscript 2:**

```
_root.onEnterFrame = function() {
  if (Key.isDown(Key.UP)) {
    _root.hero.gotoAndStop(7);
    if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
      _root.hero.prevFrame();
    } else if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
      _root.hero.nextFrame();
    }
  } else if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)) {
    _root.hero.gotoAndStop(3);
    if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
      _root.hero.nextFrame();
    } else if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
      _root.hero.prevFrame();
    }
  } else if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
    _root.hero.gotoAndStop(5);
  } else if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
    _root.hero.gotoAndStop(1);
  }
}
```